# Include paths in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a whole bunch of `.cpp` and `.h` files that are included amongst them, all in the same directory. I increased the directory level by one and added the path to the VC++ include directories on the project property. At this stage everything works fine. Then I rearranged the files in various folders all rooted to one folder though. Then I added (recursively) all the folders involved from the root folder downward to the directory list, then my project won't compile. I right click and open the files to check if they wee found and they all opened. I even right click and navigate to the definitions and declarations of members and classes and they all worked fine but the project won't compile telling me that my identifiers are undeclared.

Is there an order in which I must have added the directories? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: If it couldn't find your files, you wouldn't get 'Identifiers Undeclared'. That means it managed to find all your includes then later couldn't compile. Either you've changed something, or you've got a header with a common name and its finding a different one

Comment: If you feel a need for that many directories, you should probably split this into some library projects (I don't know if Express Edition supports that).

Comment: @MikeVine you're right, my main .cpp has the same name with one of the headers but starts with different case. I always thought case is well differentiated in C++, and I wonder why it's been working before I rearranged the files

Comment: Have you updated your project with the moved files? You need to remove the existing files in the project, and then use Add Existing files to select the files you want to be included. That way, your project is aware of your directory structure and is updated correctly.

Comment: And it helps to include the errors you get in your Q.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project,

Add only your root source folders to the C++ -> Additional includes, then add all your .CPP files to your project. All your #include <..\file.hpp> paths must be the same as the files actual location within the folder structure (you only need to specify the path below the root folder).